# VBA deleting Hyperlinks Resets Formatting

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have this vba sub that is designed to replace cell hyperlinks with the HYPERLINK function. However, the currentCell.Hyperlinks.Delete line causes all cell formatting to be reset (font, font size, bolding, underlining, cell borders, alignment, etc.). Is there any way to prevent it from doing this other than manually copying each cell property and then resetting the property after deleting the Hyperlinks? Also, it looks like setting the cell formula also resets the font, but if that is the only property that gets messed up, I can handle it.

```
Sub Test()

Dim currentCell As Range
Dim directoryBase As String

directoryBase = "\\examplePath\"

For Each currentCell In Worksheets(2).UsedRange.Cells

    If currentCell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
        currentCell.Formula = "=HYPERLINK("" + directoryBase + currentCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address + "",""ü"")"
        currentCell.Hyperlinks.Delete
        Debug.Print currentCell.Address
    End If


Next currentCell

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: What I would do is: 1) copy the format of the cell before; 2) perform your actions; 3) paste the format of the cell into the modified one. To do this, it's enough to record a macro while doing this operation manually and get the code to adapt it to your For Loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is **Matteo's** suggestion in code (using a helper cell):

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range, helper As Range
    Set helper = Range("Z100")
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If r.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
            If Intersect(r, helper) Is Nothing Then
                r.Copy helper
                r.Hyperlinks.Delete
                helper.Copy
                r.PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Just insert your formula maker into the loop after the **r.Hyperlinks.Delete**

Comment: Thanks. That helper cell was key. Was trying to copy and paste formats earlier, but the Hyperlinks.Delete was clearning the clipboard. One thing I had to add was mergeRangeAddress = r.MergeArea.Address followed by Range(mergeRangeAddress).Merge after pasting the formats because this workbook is lousy with merged cells.

Comment: Also, in my case, the formula maker depends on the hyperlinks in the cell, so it had to come before r.Hyperlinks.Delete rather than after it

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution was to call

```
Range.ClearHyperlinks
```

instead of

```
Range.Hyperlinks.Delete
```

the former clears the hyperlinks and leaves the formatting intact. Reference here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194741.aspx